# Word for an animated monster made of the body parts of dead people

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a word for this?  I'm looking for a nice colorful word with the above definition.

Examples include:

- Frankenstein's monster.
- Flesh atronach (from Elder Scrolls games).

The word is not:

- Zombie (because a zombie is an animated dead body, not cobbled or sewn together from multiple bodies).

P.S. Think there should be some kind of "reverse dictionary" or "locate a word for this definition" tag?

Comment: While I can appreciate both the question and wanting answers to it, this isn't a question suited for writer's SE. As it is purely about words and definitions (or approximate definitions) it might be more at home on English SE. Writers is more about the craft of writing, style of writing, techniques, publishing and the like, not the usage of words in and of themselves (that's English SE's thing).

Comment: I would say it is a Frankenstein's Monster in any case like this.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm looking more for a name from folklore, not a literary reference.

Comment: You might want to look at "Golem".  But "Frankenstein's Monster" (or just "Frankenstein") is most widely understood in your sense.

Comment: "golem" is quite good, but "frankenstein" is too sterile in some ways, like you get this image of a scientist in some kind of laboratory, working on metal surfaces with body parts, and electricity, and beakers of formaldehyde; i'm looking for something a little more rustic, a little more fetid, that creates a picture of a necromancer working alone in a cave, dragging heavy, lumpen sacks from the cemetery; i want you to smell the shit and decay.  Again, golem is quite good.

Comment: You’re clearly very articulate.  For future reference, it’s better to [edit] your question to add details like the above: words you’ve considered and rejected (and why), and the atmosphere / connotation that you want.  Comments are often deleted, and even when they aren’t, people don’t always see them.  … … P.S. It’s OK to write words like “you” and “me” in lower case, but “I” is always capitalized.

Comment: Also, note that [single-word-request] *is* EL&U’s “reverse dictionary” or “locate a word for this definition” tag.

Comment: Merriam-Webster has Frankenstein, Frankenstein monster, and Frankenstein's monster. If that's not good enough, there are no shortage of other versions of the story, so check reviews and articles about them.

Answer (score 1):

***golem*** can be stretched to meet the OP's definition. [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/golem) defines golem as:

> 1(in Jewish legend) a clay figure brought to life by magic.
>
> 1.1 An automaton or robot

Oxford Dictionaries (same link as above) explains the origin:

> Late 19th century: from Yiddish goylem, from Hebrew gōlem ‘shapeless
>   mass’

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/golem) says:

> 1 : an artificial human being in Hebrew folklore endowed with life
>
> 2 : something or someone resembling a golem: such as     a : automaton
>   b : blockhead

Although the original meaning was a clay or mud figure brought to life by magic, because the meaning has been extended to a robot or automaton -- or a blockhead! -- I see no reason why it cannot also be extended to a being made from the body parts of  dead people.

The body parts are inanimate, will turn into dirt eventually, and are much closer to clay or mud that are the parts of a robot.  Jumbled in a heap, or if they have been dead long enough, they are shapeless.  And if the creator of the golem  puts the parts through a industrial size mix-master so he can mold the shape of his golem, rather than assemble it jig-saw puzzle fashion, golem is indisputably the word.

Comment: golem is quite good

Comment: *I see no reason why it cannot also be extended to a being made from the body parts of dead people.* is rather like saying "I see no reason to call the people of France, German." The essence of Frankenstein's monster was that he was made of body parts. The essence of a golem is "A golem is a creature formed out of **a lifeless substance** such as dust or earth that is brought to life by ritual incantations and sequences of Hebrew letters." https://www.jmberlin.de/en/topic-golem#:~:text=A%20golem%20is%20a%20creature,of%20an%20imperiled%20Jewish%20community.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a generic term. This is why, when something is metaphorically stitched together from disparate parts in a monster-like way, it is often described as "like Frankenstein's monster" or as "a Frankenstein" (with the common confusing of the two). If there were a common generic term, people would sometimes use it in this situation.

I saw in the comments that the OP is seeking a term from folklore, but Frankenstein's monster *is* the lore for this.

Golem is not a good term. There is a well-established folklore for them and it does not include using parts of human bodies. If zombie, in the old sense of a human body reanimated and controlled by magic, is not suitable, then golem is not suitable either.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "construct" or "amalgamation" in reference to it being a gathering of disparate parts.  Some other options include...

"patchwork" from the garment industry,

"pastiche" from painting

or for a more culinary reference, "goulash" or  "salmagundi"!